# Proper refactor of a Haskell code when a non-monadic value becomes a monadic value

Tags: haskell, monads

Let's say I have this sample code:

```
h = 2
add = \x y -> (x + y)
addH = add h

main = return (fmap addH [1,2])
```

Running it evaluates to [3,4]

---

Now, let's say h is not set to "2", but to "Just 2".

**Question, part 1:**

What is the proper refactor, then, to still return [3,4] in the end?

**Question, part 2:**

Would a skilled Haskell developper prefer to change the return value to be [Just 3, Just 4]

For example with a refactor like this:

```
h = Just 2
add = \x y -> (x + y)
addH = liftM2(add) h . pure         --isn't there a better syntax for that?

main = return (fmap addH [1,2])
```

---

More generally, in an existing codebase, how to minimize the refactor impact when a function that used to return 'Num t => [t]' must now return 'Num t => [Maybe t]'?

Comment: I think a skilled developer would return `Just [3, 4]`.

Comment: What refactor would he/she do to the original code, to return Just [3, 4] ?

Comment: Use `traverse` instead of `fmap`.

Comment: Your first one doesn't return `[3, 4]`; it returns `Monad m => m [3, 4]` If you run this in GHCi, the monad defaults to `IO`, so your `IO [3, 4]` is immediately executed to produce `[3, 4]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that in your original code, `[]` and `Maybe` are redundant, and that a closer inspection of the meaning of these two functors leads to an interesting discussion. `[]` (list) represents a success or a failure in the same sense that `Maybe` does, the main difference being that `[]` can represent 0 or more values, whereas `Maybe` is limited to 0 or 1 value.

This leads to another consideration about the meaning of the `Just` in `Just 2`. What does it mean for `2` to be wrapped in a `Just`, and what would a `Nothing` mean? To take this one step further, here are five different results that you could opt for, each having a different meaning:

1. `Just [3, 4]`: There was one monolithic computation that dealt with multiple values, and it succeeded.
2. `Nothing`: There could have been a monolithic value, but there is none.
3. `[3, 4]`: There was a batch of computations, and these are the values that came out.
4. `[]`: There could have been multiple values, but there are none.
5. `[Just 3, Just 4]`: There was a batch of computations, where each computation could have failed, and all of them succeeded.

**Case 1**: If `h` represents a monolithic value, and is the unique point of failure in this computation chain, then options 1 and 2 seem like a reasonable choice. The following code accomplishes this:

```
import Control.Applicative (LiftA2)
h = Just 2
add = (+)
addH = LiftA2 add h . pure
-- Returns Just [3,4] or Nothing
mainFunc = traverse addH [1,2]
```

**Case 2**: If `add` represents a function that can fail depending on its argument (for example, think of the function `hDivBy`, which would fail on every 0), then options 3 and 4 seem like a good choice.

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)
hDivBy = \x -> (`div` x) <$> h
--Returns [1]
mainFunc = mapMaybe hDivBy [0, 2]
```

**Case 3**: If you want to keep track of element indexing, then option 5 will give you just that:

```
--Returns [Nothing, Just 2]
mainFunc = fmap hDivBy [0,2]
```

Notice that this code keeps everything in the `Applicative` realm, making it more general, [amongst other advantages](https://wiki.haskell.org/Applicative_functor#Some_advantages_of_applicative_functors).

Answer (score 0):

To acheive **Fyodor Soikin** result you can try the below one.

```
h = Just 2
add = \x y -> x + y
addH arr = pure fmap <*> (add <$> h) <*> pure arr

main = return $ addH [1, 2]
```